# Android - How one time offers work (How app identifies the Device)

Tags: android

I've seen some apps, which provide an offer(Promotional) to a device only once. If you use any other login, it will identify the device and decline the offer.
I'm sorry that I cannot give any example right now.

There are some options which are used to identify the device I read about:

- Android_ID
- Device_ID
- IMEI
- SerialNumber

which can be changed by one or another way, so which one do the popular apps use? Or is it like there's always a hack available for any method?

I searched for uniqueness of device, but it was from developers perspective to track the number of installations, I need the answer other way.

Comment: Thanks @RajanBalana !!